# the mouse cursur is blinking after I plugged second external screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, cursor, external-monitor

I plug my laptop to 2 external display monitors. When the mouse cursor is placed in the first one, everything's fine, but when I move the cursor to the second screen it starts blinking while the rest of the display is OK.
I'll mention that it's not supposed to be a cable connection issue, as I switched the connection slots of the screens (USB and HDMI) and the problem remains the same.
Do you have any guess what it could be?